# What does <T = MyType> mean?

Tags: typescript, generics

I came across this interface decleration in a [d.ts file](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/88364399e336cd5fdc494e7a18fbf7e6e0965d87/components/select/index.tsx#L53):

```
interface SelectProps<T = SelectValue> extends AbstractSelectProps { /* ... */ }
```

I haven't been able to find `<T =` in the TypeScript handbook (under [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) or [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)) nor on the [what's new in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript) page.

I'm familiar with `<T extends ...>`, which comes up repeatedly in the documentation, but this is the first time I've come across `<T = ...>`.

Is there a name for this construct? What does it mean? What is the difference between `=` and `extends`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T = Whatever` is a relatively new feature of generics, allowing you to specify a default type (absolving the consumer from passing one, if they want to go with the default).

Read more [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults).

Example:

```
abstract class Component<Props = {}, State = {}> {
  // ...
}

// Pass only the first generic for Props, State will be {}
class MyComponent extends Component<{foo: string}> {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Relevant [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)

Comment: @jcalz, thx, also just found it at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults.